# Serialize Microsoft GraphAPI RoomCollectionResponse in pyhon

Tags: python, serialization, microsoft-graph-api

I do a call to get a filtered list of rooms and want to serialize it but don't succeed.
If I do a str(result) then I get the string of results but didn't manage to return results as python list/dict.

Any idea on how to return a json serializable object? (list of dicts essentially)

(FYI: json.dumps didn't succeed in serializing)

Here is the code:

```
@app.get("/room")
async def get_room(filters: List[str]):
    """
    Get rooms from the exchange server.
    Based on API call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/room?view=graph-rest-1.0

    Returns:
        dict: List of all rooms and all room lists
    """
    logging.info("get_room")
    if not settings.is_logged_in:
        login()

    logging.info(f"get_room: filter list: {filters}.\nQuerying...")
    if filters:  # Get filtered rooms
        filters = '&'.join(filters)
        logging.info(f"filters: {filters}")
        query_params = GraphRoomRequestBuilder.GraphRoomRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(filter=filters)
        request_configuration = GraphRoomRequestBuilder.GraphRoomRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters=query_params,
        )
        result = await settings.client.places.graph_room.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
    else:  # Get all rooms
        result = await settings.client.places.graph_room.get()
    
    if result is None:
        logging.info(f"get_room: Returning NO rooms.")
        return None
    
    logging.info(f"get_room: Returning {len(result.value)} rooms.")
    return str(result)
```

And the output:

> "RoomCollectionResponse(additional_data={'@odata.context':
> 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#places/microsoft.graph.room'},
> odata_count=None, odata_next_link=None,
> value=[Room(additional_data={},
> id='b2e44b13-c914-40b1-9c11-3b076441b803',
> odata_type='#microsoft.graph.room', address=None, display_name='Room
> 2', geo_coordinates=None, phone='', audio_device_name=None,
> booking_type=<BookingType.Standard: 'standard'>, building=None,
> capacity=10, display_device_name=None,
> email_address='Room2@STEmbeddedNetwork.onmicrosoft.com',
> floor_label=None, floor_number=None, is_wheel_chair_accessible=False,
> label=None, nickname='Room 2', tags=[], video_device_name=None),
> Room(additional_data={}, id='611eebfd-e31a-4aa6-a042-a7041972fc03',
> odata_type='#microsoft.graph.room', address=None, display_name='Room
> 1', geo_coordinates=None, phone='', audio_device_name=None,
> booking_type=<BookingType.Standard: 'standard'>, building=None,
> capacity=30, display_device_name=None,
> email_address='Room1@STEmbeddedNetwork.onmicrosoft.com',
> floor_label=None, floor_number=None, is_wheel_chair_accessible=False,
> label=None, nickname='Room 1', tags=[], video_device_name=None)])"